# Facebook Application, needs to post to users feed AND the page for the Application developer, possible?

Tags: facebook

I have a Facebook application that posts to the users feed when they are using my application.

My company, which developed the Application, have their own page (as a page of my personal Facebook account).

Is it possible when the user Logs In to my app with their Facebook credentials that I can post to their feed (I can do this) AND to the feed of my Facebook business page at the same time ?

If so, any pointers/guidance would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Actually better to ask developer where he want to publish the story personal profile or page...

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible, no not at the same time and not the same feed story.

If you grant `publish_stream` permission to application this is possible without interaction of user with Feed Dialog, if not you'll need to bring Feed Dialog twice (one for personal profile and one for page publishing).

Comment: Better late than never(me). THANKS :D